# How to quickly and efficiently exclude a variables from a glm in R using Boruta output

Tags: r, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I have 96 variables in my dataframe. I want to fit a logistic regression with the variables found important by the `Boruta()` function. If there are only a handful of unimportant variables then it's easy to do something like this:

```
glm <- glm(class ~ . - X1 - X2 - X3, data = df, family = binomial)
```

However, if I have 40 unimportant variables, this becomes unfeasible. I am wondering how I could extract the names of all unimportant variables in R and if I could do something like this:

```
glm <- glm(class ~ . -unimportant, data = df, family = binomial)
```

where unimportant is a vector of the unimportant variables. I tried extracting these unimportant variables like so:

```
unimportant <- boruta_output$finalDecision[boruta_output$finalDecision == "Rejected"]
```

but this gives me a factor with three levels.

My question is:

Can I exclude variables from a model using a vector? If so how can I extract the unimportant variables from the boruta output in such a way that I can exclude many variables simultaneously?

Is there a better way of doing this?

I've tried to find a way to do this online but I only see examples of excluding a few variables as I did in the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few examples from `Boruta::Boruta`, one of these examples shows how one can fit a `randomForest` after extracting parameters using the `Boruto` algorithm. The example is shown below:

```
library(mlbench); data(Ozone)
library(randomForest)
na.omit(Ozone)->ozo
Boruta(V4~.,data=ozo,doTrace=2)->Bor.ozo
cat('Random forest run on all attributes:\n')
print(randomForest(V4~.,data=ozo))
cat('Random forest run only on confirmed attributes:\n')
print(randomForest(ozo[,getSelectedAttributes(Bor.ozo)],ozo$V4))
```

Rather than extracting the variables that should be excluded, I would continue on this example and extract variables that should be included according to the algorithm:

```
glm(class ~ ., data = df[, c('class', getSelectedAttributes(boruto_output))])
```

**Note:** that I could not test the above method, as there is no data included.